# Why does Python Selenium often result with unloaded pages?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is more of a question for my understanding (and to appease my frustrations) rather than a question on how to work around it, but as the question states; why does loading a URL/page on Selenium (with Python in my case) often not load and throws a NoSuchElementException error? I understand that as with normal browsing sometimes the webpage just doesn't load. But I'm finding between 25% - 50% of my attempts at loading a URL/page doesn't work with a 30 seconds timeout, and hence I have to retry up to 10 times with increasing timeouts between each tries before I get an instance where the URL/page finally loads.

If you could please help me understand, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your explanation.

**Sample Code**

I'm currently experimenting with https://www.carsales.com.au

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import mysql.connector
import time
import datetime

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

con = mysql.connector.connect(*****)
cursor = con.cursor()

sql_user_searches = "****"
cursor.execute(sql_user_searches)
searches = cursor.fetchall()

for z in searches:
    offset = 0
    url = "https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/{0}/{1}/".format(z[2],z[4],offset)
    sleep_time = 5
    num_retries = 100
    error = 0
    for loopingcow in range(0, num_retries):  
        try:
            error = 0
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@class="result-set-container "]""").get_attribute("outerHTML")
            print("success")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("error")
            error = 1
            pass

        if error == 1:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)  # wait before trying to fetch the data again
            sleep_time += 1  # Implement your backoff algorithm here i.e. exponential backoff
        else:
            break
    total_pagination = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[@class="tabbed-pagination"]/div[@class="pagination-container"]/div[@class="pagination-container"]/div[@class="pagination"]/p""")[0].text
    number_of_pages_split = total_pagination.split(" ")
    number_of_pages = int(number_of_pages_split[1])
    page = 0
    while page < number_of_pages:
        offset = page * 12
        url = "https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/{0}/{1}/?offset={2}".format(z[2],z[4],offset)
        print(url)
        sleep_time = 5
        num_retries = 100
        error = 0
        for loopyloop in range(0, num_retries):  
            try:
                error = 0
                driver.get(url)
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@class="result-set-container "]""").get_attribute("outerHTML")
                print("success")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("error")
                error = 1
                pass

            if error == 1:
                time.sleep(sleep_time)  # wait before trying to fetch the data again
                sleep_time += 1  # Implement your backoff algorithm here i.e. exponential backoff
            else:
                break
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[contains(@class,"listing-item")]""")
        count = len(rows)
        i = 0
        while i < count:
            title = rows[i].find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[contains(@class,"title ")]/a/h2""")[i].text
            i = i + 1
            query = """****""".format(*****)
            cursor.execute(query)
            con.commit()
        page = page + 1

cursor.close()
con.close()
driver.quit()
display.popen.kill()
print("success")
```

**Second Sample Code with 30 Seconds Timeout**

Website for this was https://www.tiket.com

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import mysql.connector
import time

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))  
display.start()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

date = int(time.strftime("%d"))
month = int(time.strftime("%m"))

con = mysql.connector.connect(*****)
cursor = con.cursor()

for z in range(11, 13):
    if z == 9:
        end_date = 31
    elif z == 10:
        end_date = 32
    elif z == 11:
        end_date = 31
    elif z == 12:
        end_date = 32
    elif z == 8:
        end_date = 32

    start_date = 1

    if z == month and (end_date - date) < 5:
        start_date = end_date
    elif z == (month + 1) and (end_date - date) < 5:
        start_date = start_date + 4 - (end_date - date)
    elif z > month:
        start_date = 1
    else:
        start_date = date

    print(z)
    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)

    for x in range(start_date, end_date):
        time.sleep(2)

        x_url = str(x).zfill(2)
        z_url = str(z).zfill(2)
        date = x_url + "-" + z_url  

        url = "https://www.tiket.com/pesawat/cari?d=DPS&a=JKT&date=2017-{1}-{0}&adult=2&child=0&infant=0".format(x_url,z_url)
        print(url)

        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(30)

        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print(last_height)

        w = 0
        while w < last_height:
            print("Success")
            w = last_height

            try:
                time.sleep(30)
                print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="tbody_depart"]""").get_attribute("outerHTML"))
                rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//tr[contains(@id,"flight")]""")
                for row in rows:            
                    airline = row.get_attribute("data-airlinesname")
                    price = row.get_attribute("data-price")
                    departure = row.get_attribute("data-depart")
                    arrival = row.get_attribute("data-arrival")
                    baggage = row.get_attribute("data-baggage")
                    stops = row.get_attribute("data-stoptext")
                    query = """****""".format(******)
                    print(query)
                    cursor.execute(query)
                    con.commit()
            except:
                driver.get(url)
                time.sleep(30)
                print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="tbody_depart"]""").get_attribute("outerHTML"))
                rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//tr[contains(@id,"flight")]""")
                for row in rows:            
                    airline = row.get_attribute("data-airlinesname")
                    price = row.get_attribute("data-price")
                    departure = row.get_attribute("data-depart")
                    arrival = row.get_attribute("data-arrival")
                    baggage = row.get_attribute("data-baggage")
                    stops = row.get_attribute("data-stoptext")
                    query = """*****""".format(*****)
                    print(query)
                    cursor.execute(query)
                    con.commit()

cursor.close()
con.close()
driver.close()
display.popen.kill()
```

Comment: Perhaps implement some `WebDriverWait().until()` in your code? Your program runs faster than you can click.

Comment: Yes, I already use waits and timeouts - 30 seconds in fact. That's not the issue. I just don't understand why even after 30 seconds the page still hasn't loaded.

Comment: Have you tried loading the page manually and compared the load time? Was it significantly different? I never noticed any timeout issue on my implementations, I'd lean towards the URL in particular just doesn't consistently load successfully regardless for users or selenium.  A sample URL and [MCVE] would help reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm frustrated. Takes on average about 3 seconds to load manually. Yet 30 seconds isn't enough for it to load with selenium. Plus I've tried quickly refreshing manually and it always loads successfully, so I don't believe it to be the URL.

Comment: I do believe if you can provide the specific URL and a [MCVE] of your code that can reproduce the issue will help shine some light on it.

Comment: Added the current code I'm working with

Comment: I don't see any 30 secs timeout? Instead of continuously hammering the site at intervals of 5s, 6s, 7s... for 100 times * 2, I'd suggest make use of the `WebDriverWait` class that you have imported and just wait until the page loads.  Perhaps the server is blocking you out because of the repeated attempts at scraping.  Other than that I don't have much suggestions.

Comment: I did initially have a 30 seconds timeout, but that didn't work as I kept waiting 30 seconds to get an error. So instead I substituted it to see if the page was going to load as soon as possible to waste as little time as possible. Judging by your response, it seems that the issue I'm experiencing isn't common or supposed to be happening. However this has been my experience ever since I have been using Selenium. Thanks for your time and input. I will continue to experiment and see if I can find the root cause - but it's at least good to know definitively that there is a root cause.

Comment: Added my previous sample code with the 30 seconds timeout with same inconsistent results.

Comment: So my guess is that manually the page *seems* to load quickly because you can see the UI, etc. but it's actually not done loading fully. Selenium is going to wait until the page is fully loaded. When you load the page manually, do you still see the spinner in the browser tab indicating that it's still loading?

Comment: Get rid of the sleep related code, e.g. `time.sleep`, and replace the `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` with a wait for visible set for 60s... now does it work? There's no point in reloading the page over and over while increasing the wait time. That's one of the main reasons sleep is bad... it's not dynamic. Use a wait and set it for the max time you want to wait. If it's done early, execution will continue. If it never finishes, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @RyanN. I am having the same issue. Did you progress any further with understanding what is causing the url load failure?

Comment: @Mischief_Monkey Unfortunately I never found a proper answer for this one, so I assumed it was my internet connection/system or possibly even a script on the site to deter scraping. But the looping incrementing sleep method I used in my original sample code worked a treat to keep trying until the page loaded - although it just slowed down the process somewhat.

Comment: @RyanN. I did a little more searching on the net and came across a blog that suggests to check http://example.com/robots.txt file. If the website is anti scrapping it is listed here. This helped me understand a bit better where the scrapping was failing.